# Chrome not showing fonts for github website

Tags: unity, google-chrome, fonts

I am not currently able to see github website repos. It looks something like this:

[image]

I have installed ms truetype fonts and the roboto fonts. Then ran `fc-cache -fvs`. And chrome is not rendering fonts for github. That is the only website currently I know which doesn't show fonts. However, this works fine on firefox.

I tried re-installing chrome, restarting pc, rerunning fc-cache, restoring to default fonts from unity tweak font settings, but no success.

**Edit:**  It happens with medium also:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after a day, I was finally able to solve this issue. The font I have installed by putting in `~/.fonts` folder was not working. I went to that folder from the file manager and it failed to display fonts from the `.ttf` file and also clicking on `Install` gave an error `Install failed`.

I have dual boot `Ubuntu 16.04` with `Windwos 10`. So what worked is installing `Segoe UI` fonts from the `Windows/fonts` directory. Open the windwos installation drive in file manager, navigate to windows/fonts folder. Search `segoeui`, open each of the search result and click on top right corner `Install`. After doing it all, run `fc-cache -fv`  and log out. Now login to see the Segoe UI fonts all over!

Hope this helps someone.